# Jupyter Notebook Anaconda cannot open because of syntax error with dateutil

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, python-dateutil

I'm trying to open Jupyter Notebook with Anaconda navigator (on Mac OSX) and I cannot open it properly. I keep getting this message in my terminal.

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py", line 158
    l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, `value`))
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

I tried checking my default version of python and it says my default version is python 3.6. However when I got to pip and try to install dateutil it says

```
pip install python-dateutil
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

I am having trouble since I have multiple versions of python on my computer. What can I do?

Comment: I can tell you that the line of code you present is indeed a syntax error.  Python doesn't recognize the backquote character as valid syntax.  I can't put that character into this comment because it has special meaning in an SO post, but it's the one that the caret is pointing to in front of the word "value".  It appears that the dateutil module you downloaded might be defective.

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same problem with anconda 4.5.1 python 3.6. Reinstalling the package solved the problem for me.

```
pip uninstall python-dateutil
pip install python-dateutil
```

Comment: this answer worked for me. my error started because i pip installed an app (heroku) that overwrote my python-dateutil. uninstalling and reinstalling helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the python version for Anaconda. Currently, your Anaconda looks into python 2.7 directory and I think you need to switch to python 3.6 version.

You can create environments for different versions of Python and installed packages by:

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda
```

py36 is the name of the python 3.6.0 environment.

Then you can activate an environment by

```
source activate py36
```

Helpful links:

[Using pip in an environment](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment)

[Managing Python in Anaconda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#managing-python)

[Managing Environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#managing-environments)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm still having problems, where even with the environment it keeps using the /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python 
I tried sudo pip install python-dateutil --upgrade but that didn't work either.

Comment: Maybe you should this try: conda install python=3.6.0 (source: http://chris35wills.github.io/conda_python_version/)

Comment: @A.N. did you solve the problem? Please let me know if you need any further assistance

Comment: It still isn't working. I tried that but I got "UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - backports.functools_lru_cache -> python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0 -> openssl 1.0.1*
  - python 3.6.0*
"

Comment: @A.N. I'm so sorry about this. I just edited my answer for you. First you need to create an environment for anaconda python 3.6 (name it py36). Then you activated the environment py36. Please try that again and copy and paste any problems along the way.